# how to find datarows with biggest value?

Tags: sql-server, simplification

So given

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 7 |

I want to query the rows with biggest b, however I dont know that biggest b would be 3 in this case.
Same query should return the last two rows here aswell:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |

What I do is quite literally look the biggest value up and then query for it.

```
SELECT a,c FROM [table] t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT a, MAX(b) as maxb FROM [table] GROUP BY a) t2 ON t2.a = t1.a
WHERE t1.b = t2.maxb
```

It feels so clunky to do, although it feels like a simple concept.
Is this the real solution?

Comment: SQL Server can use the "segment top" optimisation and the SQL in the question can give a simple plan https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/07/the-segment-top-query-optimisation.html but other approaches in the dupe